# Best way for custom sorting in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I am a C++ programmer and I am using Java at the moment (I do have a considerable amount of java experience).

Basically, I want to recreate the `pair<int,int>` that I so commonly use in C++ and I want to have it sorted by the second integer value.

I am searching up on the internet and trying different ways of going about this, including using Comparator, Comparable etc.

I am basically creating a test program that looks like this:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

class PairTest
{

    public static void main (String args[])  // entry point from OS
    {
        new PairTest().run();


    }

    public void run (){
        Pair foo = new Pair(1,2);
        System.out.println(foo.first + " "+ foo.second);
        ArrayList <Pair> al = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        for(int i =10;i>0;i--){
            al.add(new Pair(i, i*2));
        }
        for(int i =0;i<al.size();i++){
            System.out.println(al.get(i).first + " " + al.get(i).second);
        }
        Collections.sort(al);
        for(int i =0;i<al.size();i++){
            System.out.println(al.get(i).first + " " + al.get(i).second);
        }
    }

    private class Pair implements Comparable{

        public int first;
        public int second;

        public Pair (int a, int b){
            this.first = a;
            this.second = b;

        }

        int compareTo (Pair o){
            return new Integer(this.second).compareTo(new Integer(o.second));
        }
    }

}
```

What would be the best way to go about making a custom sorting function so the ArrayList sorts by the "second" variable. I want a quick and safe way of doing it, and at the moment, the compiler is telling me that "PairTest.Pair does not override abstract method compareTo..."

I really don't know whats going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I tried that with the appropriate casting, but my program gave me trouble when calling Collections.sort();

Comment: Instead of a sorted pair in a list, a common pattern is to use a Map, provided the values are unique (There are solution even when its not) e.g. try `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` where the value you are sorting on is the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your `Pair` class: it does not declare a generic parameter and the `compareTo` method needs to be `public`. Also, it is more efficient to just return the difference between int values than to construct `Integer` objects and invoke `compareTo`. Try this:

```
private class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {

    public int first;
    public int second;

    public Pair (int a, int b){
        this.first = a;
        this.second = b;

    }

    public int compareTo (Pair o){
        return second < o.second ? -1 : (second == o.second ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that did the trick! (It seems that the Comparable<Pair> was causing most of the problem)

Comment: Not that hack again.. The given compareTo version was correct, this one is not. For example 2**30 certainly is larger than -2**30. One of my profs used to say `If it doesn't have to be correct I can make it arbitrarily fast`..

Comment: @Voo - Good point. I updated the code to avoid overflow issues; it should be correct in all cases now. While the original compareTo was correct, it was terribly inefficient--requiring two Integer objects for every comparison.

Comment: @Ted Perfect +1 Just note that there's `Integer.compare()` which is imo the nicest solution. But then they've implemented it exactly identical to your solution.

Comment: @Voo - Nice point about `Integer.compare()`; it is the most readable solution. However, it did not exist prior to Java 7 and not everyone is using the latest Java.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you should change:

```
private class Pair implements Comparable
```

to

```
private class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>
```

And you change this line:

```
int compareTo (Pair o)
```

to

```
public int compareTo (Pair o)
```

because this function will be use outside of this class :)

That's all you need :)

Comment: +1 for being short and concise, but someone already beat you to it by giving me an example on how the program should look like :)

Answer (score 1):

Override `comapreTo` method in your `Pair` class. No need to implement anything.

`comapreTo` method accepts `Object` as the argument

```
public int compareTo(Object another)
{
    return new Integer(this.second).compareTo(new Integer(((Pair)another).second));
}
```